# Insert a function in an ASP tag

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net

I want to call a function in an ASP tag. The code is:

`<asp:LinkButton ID="Link_Primera_Pag" runat="server" CssClass="link"><< Primera</asp:LinkButton>`

I tried the following:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="Link_Primera_Pag" runat="server" CssClass="link"><< <% Traduce(Primera) %></asp:LinkButton>
```

The error displayed is:

Traduce is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.

Traduce is a method created in a visual basic file and it works right.

How can I call the method in asp code?

Thanks

Comment: `<asp:LinkButton Text='<%# Traduce(Primera) %>' ...`

Comment: Change your function's access modifier to public...

Answer (score 1):

Probably your function is inaccessible as it said in error.
Try declare it as public.

```
    public string Traduce(...)
```